# Как передать метод в метод класса PHP?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь передать метод в другой метод класса. Например, с функциями это работает так:

```
function a($a)
{
    $a();
}

function b()
{
    echo '1231231';
}

$d = a('b');
```

Хочу такое сделать с методами класса, но не работает. Пробовал так:

```
class Test
{
    public function c() {
        $this->aa($this->b);
    }

    public function b()
    {
        echo '1231231';
    }

    public function aa($a)
    {
        $a();
    }
}

$inst = new Test();

$inst->c();
```

Есть ли способ решить такую проблему?

Comment: `[$this, 'b']` вы хотите передать, надо полагать, а не `$this->b`

Comment: @teran, я хочу передать туда метод, как, например, в JS. Можно и массивом, если это сработает.

Comment: когда просто "метод" это обычная функция как в вашем первом примере. В данном случае этоне метод, а метод класса. Передаваться такой метод может либо с контекстом (объект) либо статически (сам класс). В данном случае с привязкой к экземпляру объекта. Так что ссылки на методы объекта/класса передаются в таком виде, в смысле что таков формат записи, а не просто невнятный массив. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.callable.php

Comment: Ок, спасибо, а как тогда передать такой метод как callback, например, сюда: https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_action

Comment: А вызывать его потом как? `$a[0]->$a[1]();` Так что-то не очень выходит.

Comment: без понятия как работает WP, но судя по описанию вы должны написать какое-то `add_action('hook-name', [$this, 'b'],...)`. А вызов данного метода это уже не ваша забота. Вызвать его потом просто как `$a()`. В вашем примере ничего кроме указанного мною в первом комментарии не изменяется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->b` это обращение к члену класса, объявленному как, например, `private $b`. Вы же хотите передать ссылку на метод объекта. Поскольку речь идет об обычном (не статичном) методе класса, то передается такая ссылки в виде `[$this, 'b']`. То есть адрес объекта и метод, который надо вызвать.

В случае статического метода передавать надо метод класса и имя метода, например, `[A:classname, 'b']`.

Входящий параметр для функций обратного вызова можно описать как `callable`

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.callable.php